# Why don't changes to my prop update the dom?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

TL;DR fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/neon1024/3zn9arj3/4/

```html
<div id="app">
    <repos v-bind:repos='[{id: 1, full_name: "davidyell/app", description: "Daves custom CakePHP 3.0 app template"}, {id: 2, full_name: "davidyell/app-template", description: "An empty 2.4 cakephp application template, for use with composer"}]'></repos>
</div>
```

```js
Vue.component('repos', {
    template: `
      <div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="(repo, index) in repos">
                {{ repo.full_name }} -> {{ repo.description }}
                <span v-on:click="removeIt" style="color:red;cursor:pointer" v-bind:data-index="index">Delete</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  `,
    props: {
        repos: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        removeIt(event) {
            this.repos.splice(event.target.dataset.index, 1);
            console.log(this.repos);
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

I am passing data into my component using a prop, and I would like to be able to delete items and have the dom update.

However when I delete, the internal state of the prop changes, but the dom does not update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed a static (non-reactive) array to the component. You need to add the array to data to make it reactive.

When you add a javascript object to data, Vue converts it into an *observed* value. When you pass an inline array, as you do in the code in the question, the array is *not* observed, and Vue doesn't know to update the DOM.

```js
Vue.component('repos', {
    template: `
      <div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="(repo, index) in repos">
                {{ repo.full_name }} -> {{ repo.description }}
                <span v-on:click="removeIt" style="color:red;cursor:pointer" v-bind:data-index="index">Delete</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  `,
    props: {
        repos: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
     removeIt(event) {
   this.repos.splice(event.target.dataset.index, 1);
            console.log(this.repos);
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
      repos: [{id: 1, full_name: "davidyell/app", description: "Daves custom CakePHP 3.0 app template"}, {id: 2, full_name: "davidyell/app-template", description: "An empty 2.4 cakephp application template, for use with composer"}]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <repos v-bind:repos='repos'></repos>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually sidesteps the problem, by including the data in the Vue component. The premise is that the data comes from elsewhere, and needs to be given to the component. So I need to somehow copy the prop into the components data?

Comment: @DavidYell That's not really the question asked, however. You either need to make the data reactive, or force the DOM to update. https://jsfiddle.net/3zn9arj3/6/

Comment: I've managed to get it working by copying the object to the data in the created method.

Comment: Sure, there are any number of ways to do that as well. https://jsfiddle.net/3zn9arj3/8/